# Como abrir modal com resultados no botão submit?

Tags: javascript, modal

*Bom, desculpem a pergunta.*

*Não sei muita coisa em Javascript, queria saber como eu mostro os resultados do meu formulário dentro da modal, normalmente estou clicando e está redirecionando para outra pagina.*

**Segue o codigo abaixo:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            <!--DEFINE AS FONTES USADA NAS PERGUNTAS E RESPOSTAS-->
            #center{font-family:arial;font-size:8pt;color:#696969;}
            #pergunta{background-color:#fefefe;font-family:arial;font-size:8pt;color:#696969;}
            #resposta{background-color:#fefefe;font-family:arial;font-size:8pt;color:#696969;}
            #input{border:1px solid #cccccc;background-color:#fefefe;font-family:arial;font-size:8pt;color:#696969;}
            #normal{font-family:arial;font-size:8pt;color:#696969;text-decoration:none;}
            input{font-family:arial;font-size:8pt;color:#1c1c1c;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- MODAL -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- JANELA MODAL-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Resultados</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Resultados exibem aqui dentro</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- FIM MODAL -->

        <!--ABAIXO SEGUE O FORMULÁRIO-->
        <form name=formmail>
            <center><font id=center>Responda as perguntas abaixo</font></center>
            <br>
            <center><font id=normal>cada questão vale 1 ponto</font></center>
            <center><a href=# onClick="vai()"><font id=normal>[ Clique aqui para fazer Novamente ]</font></a></center>
            <center><font id=normal>[ marque somente uma questão por pergunta ]</font></center>
            <div align=center> 
                <table border=0 cellpading=3 cellspacing=3 style="border:1px solid #f8f8f8;background-color:#ffffff;" width=400>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <font id=pergunta> 
                            Coloque ao lado o seu Nome:&nbsp;</font><input type="text" name="onome" value="" size=44 id=input><font color=#0099cc face=verdana size=1><b>&nbsp;*</b><br>
                            <font id=pergunta> 
                            1 - Que número é este [1]?</font>
                            <br><font id=resposta> 
                            <font id=pergunta>(A)</font><input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="question1" VALUE="A"><font id=resposta>Um<br>
                            <font id=pergunta>(B)</font><input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="question1" VALUE="B"><font id=resposta>Dois<br>
                            <font id=pergunta>(C)</font><input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="question1" VALUE="C"><font id=resposta>Três<br>
                            <br>
                            <font id=pergunta> 
                            2 - Que número é este [6]?</font>
                            <br> 
                            <font id=pergunta>(A)</font><input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="question2" VALUE="A"><font id=resposta>Cinco<br>
                            <font id=pergunta>(B)</font><input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="question2" VALUE="B"><font id=resposta>Seis<br>
                            <font id=pergunta>(C)</font><input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="question2" VALUE="C"><font id=resposta>Sete<br>
                            <br>
                            <font id=pergunta> 
                            3 - Que letra é esta [c]?</font>
                            <br> 
                            <font id=pergunta>(A)</font><input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="question3" VALUE="A"><font id=resposta>b<br>
                            <font id=pergunta>(B)</font><input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="question3" VALUE="B"><font id=resposta>c<br>
                            <font id=pergunta>(C)</font><input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="question3" VALUE="C"><font id=resposta>d<br>
                            <br>
                            <center>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Resultado</button>
                                <input TYPE="button" NAME="valide" VALUE="Resultado" onclick="javascript:solution(this.form);" style="border:1px solid #f8f8f8;background-color:#ffffff;color:#696969;"> 
                            </center>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table> 
            </div>
            <center><a href=# onClick="vai()"><font id=normal>[ Clique aqui para fazer Novamente ]</font></a></center>
        </form>

<script language="JavaScript"> 
/* início do código  */
var pontos = 0;
function reponse(form) {
    for (var i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
        if (form[i].checked) {
            break
        }
    }
    var answer = ""
    if (i < form.length) {
        answer = form[i].value
    }
    return answer;
}

function solution(form) {
    /* variável para cada pergunta */
    var points = 0;
    var rep = "";
    var comment = "";
    var resposta1 = "";
    var resposta2 = "";
    var resposta3 = "";
    var onome = ""

    /* valor de pontos para as questões */
    if (reponse(form.question1) == "A") {
        pontos += 1
    }
    if (reponse(form.question2) == "B") {
        pontos += 1
    }
    if (reponse(form.question3) == "B") {
        pontos += 1
    }

    /* cada mensagem vai de acordo com o input marcado para resposta */

    /* mensagem para questão 1 */
    if (reponse(form.question1) == "") {
        resposta1 = "<font color=#cccccc>Você não respondeu está resposta!</font>"
    }
    if (reponse(form.question1) == "A") {
        resposta1 = "<font color=#0099cc>correta</font>"
    }
    if (reponse(form.question1) == "B") {
        resposta1 = "<font color=#cccccc>incorreta</font>"
    }
    if (reponse(form.question1) == "C") {
        resposta1 = "<font color=#cccccc>incorreta</font>"
    }

    /* mensagem para questão 2 */
    if (reponse(form.question2) == "") {
        resposta2 = "<font color=#cccccc>Você não respondeu está resposta!</font>"
    }
    if (reponse(form.question2) == "A") {
        resposta2 = "<font color=#cccccc>incorreta</font>"
    }
    if (reponse(form.question2) == "B") {
        resposta2 = "<font color=#0099cc>correta</font>"
    }
    if (reponse(form.question2) == "C") {
        resposta2 = "<font color=#cccccc>incorreta</font>"
    }

    /* mensagem para questão 3 */
    if (reponse(form.question3) == "") {
        resposta3 = "<font color=#cccccc>Você não respondeu está resposta!</font>"
    }
    if (reponse(form.question3) == "A") {
        resposta3 = "<font color=#cccccc>incorreta</font>"
    }
    if (reponse(form.question3) == "B") {
        resposta3 = "<font color=#0099cc>correta</font>"
    }
    if (reponse(form.question3) == "C") {
        resposta3 = "<font color=#cccccc>incorreta</font>"
    }

    /* aqui é exibido a mensagem de acordo com o ponto marcado */
    if (pontos == 0) {
        comment = "você não fez pontos, tente novamente"
    }
    if (pontos == 1) {
        comment = "você fez um ponto, continue assim"
    }
    if (pontos == 2) {
        comment = "você fez 2 pontos, está quase lá"
    }
    if (pontos == 3) {
        comment = "excelente! você acertou todas!<br><br><br><button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-lg' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>Open Modal</button>"
    }

    /* aqui exibo a porcentagem de acordo com o ponto  */
    if (pontos == 0) {
        porcentagem = "0%"
    }
    if (pontos == 1) {
        porcentagem = "33%"
    }
    if (pontos == 2) {
        porcentagem = "66%"
    }
    if (pontos == 3) {
        porcentagem = "100%"
    }

    /* aqui inicio o código mostrado na nova janela */
    chaine = '' +
        '<head><title>Resultado</title>' +
        '<style type=text/css>a{font-family:arial;font-size:8pt;color:#696969;text-decoration:none;}#texto{font-family:verdana,arial;font-size:8pt;color:#696969;}#textos{font-family:verdana,arial;font-size:10px;color:#c7c7c7;}input{border:1px solid #f8f8f8;background-color:fefefe;font-family:arial;font-size:8pt;color:#1c1c1c;}#resultado{font-family:arial;font-size:8pt;color:#696969;}</style>' +
        '</head>' +
        '<center><font id=texto>Você atingiu um total de <font color=#0099cc><b>' + pontos + '</b></font> pontos, acertando ' + porcentagem + ' das questões.<br><br><font color=#696969>' + comment + '<BR>'

        +
        '<br><center><font id=texto>' + formmail.onome.value + ' veja abaixo o resumo das questões:</font></center><br>'

        +
        '<table border=0 cellpading=3 cellspacing=3 style="border:1px solid #f8f8f8;background-color:#ffffff;" width="150">' +
        "<tr><td><font id=textos>1)</td><td><font id=resultado>" + resposta1 + "</font></td></tr>" +
        "<tr><td><font id=textos>2)</td><td><font id=resultado>" + resposta2 + "</font></td></tr>" +
        "<tr><td><font id=textos>3)</td><td><font id=resultado>" + resposta3 + "</font></td></tr>" +
        "</table></form>" +
        '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:window.close()">FECHAR</a>' +
        '</CENTER></BODY></HTML>'

    solu = open();
    solu.document.write(chaine)
}

function vai() {
    location.reload();
}

</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LeoS isso é mais simples do que parece, quando você aperta o botão `resultado` (o pequeno) ele já cria um corpo em html, você só precisa jogar isso dentro do seu modal.

Vamos lá, no final do seu código tem essas duas linhas:

> solu=open();
>
> solu.document.write(chaine)

O que você precisa fazer é substituir essas linhas pelo seguinte:

```
$('.modal-body').html(chaine);    #aqui você vai jogar seu conteúdo no corpo do modal
$('#myModal').modal('toggle');    #aqui você vai mandar o modal abrir
```

*** Importante você precisa tirar todos os códigos desnecessários do corpo do modal ex: as tags `<html><body><head>` entre outras.

Aqui tem o código que eu editei:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
<!--DEFINE AS FONTES USADA NAS PERGUNTAS E RESPOSTAS-->
#center{font-family:arial;font-size:8pt;color:#696969;}
#pergunta{background-color:#fefefe;font-family:arial;font-size:8pt;color:#696969;}
#resposta{background-color:#fefefe;font-family:arial;font-size:8pt;color:#696969;}
#input{border:1px solid #cccccc;background-color:#fefefe;font-family:arial;font-size:8pt;color:#696969;}
#normal{font-family:arial;font-size:8pt;color:#696969;text-decoration:none;}
input{font-family:arial;font-size:8pt;color:#1c1c1c;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <!-- MODAL -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- JANELA MODAL-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Resultados</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Resultados exibem aqui dentro</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- FIM MODAL -->
  

<!--ABAIXO SEGUE O FORMULÁRIO-->
<form name=formmail>
<center><font id=center>Responda as perguntas abaixo</font></center>
<br>
<center><font id=normal>cada questão vale 1 ponto</font></center>
<center><a href=# onClick="vai()"><font id=normal>[ Clique aqui para fazer Novamente ]</font></a></center>
<center><font id=normal>[ marque somente uma questão por pergunta ]</font></center>
<div align=center> 
<table border=0 cellpading=3 cellspacing=3 style="border:1px solid #f8f8f8;background-color:#ffffff;" width=400>
<tr><td>
<font id=pergunta> 
Coloque ao lado o seu Nome:&nbsp;</font><input type="text" name="onome" value="" size=44 id=input><font color=#0099cc face=verdana size=1><b>&nbsp;*</b><br>
<font id=pergunta> 
1 - Que número é este [1]?</font>
<br><font id=resposta> 
<font id=pergunta>(A)</font><input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="question1" VALUE="A"><font id=resposta>Um<br>
<font id=pergunta>(B)</font><input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="question1" VALUE="B"><font id=resposta>Dois<br>
<font id=pergunta>(C)</font><input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="question1" VALUE="C"><font id=resposta>Três<br>
<br>
<font id=pergunta> 
2 - Que número é este [6]?</font>
<br> 
<font id=pergunta>(A)</font><input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="question2" VALUE="A"><font id=resposta>Cinco<br>
<font id=pergunta>(B)</font><input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="question2" VALUE="B"><font id=resposta>Seis<br>
<font id=pergunta>(C)</font><input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="question2" VALUE="C"><font id=resposta>Sete<br>
<br>
<font id=pergunta> 
3 - Que letra é esta [c]?</font>
<br> 
<font id=pergunta>(A)</font><input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="question3" VALUE="A"><font id=resposta>b<br>
<font id=pergunta>(B)</font><input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="question3" VALUE="B"><font id=resposta>c<br>
<font id=pergunta>(C)</font><input TYPE="checkbox" NAME="question3" VALUE="C"><font id=resposta>d<br>
<br>
<center>
<input TYPE="button" NAME="valide" VALUE="Resultado" onclick="javascript:solution(this.form);" style="border:1px solid #f8f8f8;background-color:#ffffff;color:#696969;"> 
</center></td></form></tr>
</table> 
<center><a href=# onClick="vai()"><font id=normal>[ Clique aqui para fazer Novamente ]</font></a></center>

<script language="JavaScript"> 
/* início do código  */
<!-- 
var pontos=0; 
function reponse(form) { 
for (var i=0;i<form.length;i++){ 
 if (form[i].checked){ 
  break 
 } 
} 
var answer="" 
if (i<form.length){ 
 answer = form[i].value 
} 
return answer; 
} 

function solution(form) { 
/* variável para cada pergunta */
var points=0;var rep="";var comment="";var resposta1="";var resposta2="";var resposta3="";var onome=""

/* valor de pontos para as questões */
if (reponse(form.question1)=="A") {pontos+=1} 
if (reponse(form.question2)=="B") {pontos+=1} 
if (reponse(form.question3)=="B") {pontos+=1} 

/* cada mensagem vai de acordo com o input marcado para resposta */

/* mensagem para questão 1 */
if (reponse(form.question1)=="") {resposta1="<font color=#cccccc>Você não respondeu está resposta!</font>"} 
if (reponse(form.question1)=="A") {resposta1="<font color=#0099cc>correta</font>"} 
if (reponse(form.question1)=="B") {resposta1="<font color=#cccccc>incorreta</font>"}
if (reponse(form.question1)=="C") {resposta1="<font color=#cccccc>incorreta</font>"}

/* mensagem para questão 2 */
if (reponse(form.question2)=="") {resposta2="<font color=#cccccc>Você não respondeu está resposta!</font>"} 
if (reponse(form.question2)=="A") {resposta2="<font color=#cccccc>incorreta</font>"} 
if (reponse(form.question2)=="B") {resposta2="<font color=#0099cc>correta</font>"}
if (reponse(form.question2)=="C") {resposta2="<font color=#cccccc>incorreta</font>"}

/* mensagem para questão 3 */
if (reponse(form.question3)=="") {resposta3="<font color=#cccccc>Você não respondeu está resposta!</font>"} 
if (reponse(form.question3)=="A") {resposta3="<font color=#cccccc>incorreta</font>"} 
if (reponse(form.question3)=="B") {resposta3="<font color=#0099cc>correta</font>"}
if (reponse(form.question3)=="C") {resposta3="<font color=#cccccc>incorreta</font>"}

/* aqui é exibido a mensagem de acordo com o ponto marcado */
if (pontos==0) {comment="você não fez pontos, tente novamente"}
if (pontos==1) {comment="você fez um ponto, continue assim"}
if (pontos==2) {comment="você fez 2 pontos, está quase lá"}
if (pontos==3) {comment="excelente! você acertou todas!"}

/* aqui exibo a porcentagem de acordo com o ponto  */
if (pontos==0) {porcentagem="0%"}
if (pontos==1) {porcentagem="33%"}
if (pontos==2) {porcentagem="66%"}
if (pontos==3) {porcentagem="100%"}

/* aqui inicio o código mostrado na nova janela */
chaine='' 
+'<center><font id=texto>Você atingiu um total de <font color=#0099cc><b>'+ pontos +'</b></font> pontos, acertando '+ porcentagem +' das questões.<br><br><font color=#696969>'+comment+'<BR>' 

+'<br><center><font id=texto>'+ formmail.onome.value +' veja abaixo o resumo das questões:</font></center><br>'

+'<table border=0 cellpading=3 cellspacing=3 style="border:1px solid #f8f8f8;background-color:#ffffff;" width="150">'
+"<tr><td><font id=textos>1)</td><td><font id=resultado>"+ resposta1 +"</font></td></tr>"
+"<tr><td><font id=textos>2)</td><td><font id=resultado>"+ resposta2 +"</font></td></tr>"
+"<tr><td><font id=textos>3)</td><td><font id=resultado>"+ resposta3 +"</font></td></tr>"
+"</table></form>"
+'</CENTER>' 

$('.modal-body').html(chaine);
$('#myModal').modal('toggle');

} 
//--> 
</script>
<script>
function vai() {
location.reload()
}
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dúvida resolvida, dei uma editada no codigo.. e estou com outra dúvida e se tipo eu quiser fazer um campo <select><option>1, 2, 3.. Como faço pra pegar o resultado dessse option?

Comment: Esse valor vai ser o mesmo valor do select, se você quer pegar ele pelo js pode ser pelo jquery `$('#id_select').val();`

Answer (score 1):

Vou deixar um exemplo pra que você use como base e adapte as suas necessidades, esta foi a forma que encontrei, mas devem haver outras de chegar a este mesmo resultado.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <form action="link" method="POST" id="formulario">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <label>Qual é o seu nome?</label>
                <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Digite seu nome" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <label>Pergunta 1</label>
                <input type="text" id="nome" name="pergunta1" placeholder="Resposta: " class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <label>Pergunta 2</label>
                <input type="text" name="pergunta2" placeholder="Resposta: " class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <label>Pergunta 3</label>
                <input type="text" name="pergunta3" placeholder="Resposta: " class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix">&nbsp</div>
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" >
                <input type="submit" id="enviar" name="enviar" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-success">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- MODAL -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Resultados</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="conteudo">
                    <p>Resultados exibem aqui dentro</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#enviar").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
        var nome = $("#nome").val();
        $("#conteudo").empty();
        $("#conteudo").append("Nome: " + nome);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sugiro que teste o código fora do SOpt pq por algum motivo está excluindo alguns `id`s